がら instead of から, is this Tsugaru dialect or a lisp or an error in subtitle?
In The Makanai's second episode, within the first few minutes, Kenta says 今がら朝練なんだ. At first, I thought that this was a Netflix subtitle error, but then I listened again to the dialogue and he really does say がら instead of から. Furthermore, the grandmother he's talking to also says 食ってぐか instead of 食ってくか.
Is this something common in Tsugaru dialect (the dialect of Aomori where the characters live) and is this an example of 鼻濁音 which is prevalent in Tsugaru dialect? Or is this perhaps a lisp or accent? Or am I mistaking the k-turn-g sound for actual Japanese phrases?

Related? https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/74795/9831

This がら is an example of eye dialect used to simulate Tohoku-ben. See this answer and this Wikipedia article. While 鼻濁音 is indeed more prevalent in eastern or northern parts of Japan, this term is used to distinguish the two types of が ([ga]/[ŋa]). When か becomes が, this phenomenon is called 有声化/濁音化 (voicing).

I have heard of 半濁点 being used to indicate the ŋ sound, like か゚. (That uses a combining character; I don't know my IME very well, so I had to use some special tricks to create it.) Anyway, I think some English-native listeners would have trouble distinguishing [ga] from [ŋa] in an unfamiliar context. Or rather, it might simply not register as phonemic, because there are a lot of other explanations for such a nasal pronunciation in English, among English speakers (a cold, putting on a silly voice, social anxiety...).

@KarlKnechtel Some experts use the 半濁点 notation to represent ŋ, but ordinary Japanese speakers are no better than English speakers at distinguishing [ga] and [ŋa]. Most people are simply unaware that they're different.
